# Is there way to handle the missing data when converting to avro, which does not even have nulls

Tags: avro

We are converting a json data to Avro and we have defined the complete schema. However, we are facing issues with missing fields. 
We have ensured the field is defined with [null or filed data] union, but it does not work if the field is not at all present in the json data. What is the way to handle the missing fields which are not presented in the data at all.?

Eg:

### Schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Str",
  "namespace" : "com.srini.avromeetup",
  "doc" : "Schema for com.srini.avromeetup.Str",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "str",
    "type" :  "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "str2",
    "type" : "string"
  } ]
}
```

### Input: That works:

```
{
  "str" : {"string":"abcd"},
  "str2" : null
}
```

### Input that is giving me problem:

```
{
  "str" : {"string":"abcd"}
}
```

How can i handle if the data is not at all present in the json.

Thank You,
Regards, 
Srini.